# C++ check if web browser closed

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, codeblocks

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <exdisp.h>

class CWebBrowser{

    public:
        HRESULT hr;
        IWebBrowserApp *www;

    HRESULT init(){
        CLSID clsid;
        const IID IID_IEApplication = {0x0002DF05,0x0000,0x0000,{0xC0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x46}};

        if(www) hr = www->put_Visible(-1);
        if(hr!=0 || www==NULL){
            QuitBrowser();
            hr=CLSIDFromProgID(L"InternetExplorer.Application",&clsid);
            if(hr==0) hr=CoCreateInstance(clsid,NULL,CLSCTX_ALL,IID_IEApplication,reinterpret_cast<void**>(&www));
            if(hr==0) hr = www->put_Visible(-1);
        }
    return hr;
   }

    HRESULT browse(BSTR addr){
        VARIANT vEmpty;
        VariantInit(&vEmpty);

        hr=www->Navigate(addr, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty);
        VariantClear(&vEmpty);

    return hr;
    }

    void QuitBrowser(){
        if(www){
            www->Quit();
            www->Release();
            www=NULL;
        }
    }

    CWebBrowser(){
        hr=CoInitialize(NULL);
    }

    ~CWebBrowser(){
        if(www){
            www->Quit();
            www->Release();
            www=NULL;
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
};
```

I am calling the init() function to check if Web Browser is still open before browse() another webpage.

When I run the app the first time there are 2 processes showing in Task Manager (iexplorer.exe) & (iexplorer.exe *32)

When I close the app sometimes processes close and sometimes they don't.

Sometimes (iexplorer.exe *32) closes and only (iexplorer.exe) is open. When I try calling init() in this case the app crashes.

Using CodeBlocks 17.12, Windows 2000 & IE 11.

Comment: may be do init every time before browse will help?

Comment: that creates a new instance. I wont be able to do things like log into a website as the session will be invalid.

Comment: Yes, but AFAIK you can check/get running app instance with GetActiveObject before. If it fails, call CoCreateInstance if needed

Comment: [DWebBrowserEvents2::OnQuit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768340(v%3dvs.85)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me.  Maybe you are calling `www->Release()` prematurely.

Here is my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <Exdisp.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment (lib, "SHDOCVW.lib")

IWebBrowserApp *www;

HRESULT init()
{
    CLSID clsid;
    const IID IID_IEApplication = {0x0002DF05,0x0000,0x0000,{0xC0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x46}};
    HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID (L"InternetExplorer.Application", &clsid);

    if (hr)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << "CLSIDFromProgID failed, error " << hr << "\n";
        return hr;
    }

    hr = CoCreateInstance (clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IEApplication, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&www));
    if (hr)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << "CoCreateInstance failed, error " << hr << "\n";
        return hr;
    }

    hr = www->put_Visible(-1);
    if (hr)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << "put_Visible failed, error " << hr << "\n";
        www->Release ();
        www = nullptr;
        return hr;
    }

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT browse(BSTR addr)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    if (www)
    {
        VARIANT vEmpty;
        VariantInit (&vEmpty);
        hr = www->Navigate (addr, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty);
        VariantClear (&vEmpty);
    }

    return hr;
}

int main ()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx (NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    assert (hr == 0);
    int mb_result;

    while (1)
    {
        hr = init ();

        if (hr == 0)
        {
            mb_result = MessageBoxW (NULL, L"About to browse", L"Browser Test", MB_OKCANCEL);
            if (mb_result == IDOK)
            {
                BSTR url = SysAllocString (L"https://www.google.com");
                hr = browse (url);
                SysFreeString (url);
                if (hr)
                    std::cout << "browse () returned: " << std::hex << hr << "\n";
            }

            mb_result = MessageBoxW (NULL, L"About to quit", L"Browser Test", MB_OKCANCEL);
            if (mb_result == IDOK)
                www->Quit ();
            www->Release ();
            www = nullptr;
        }

        mb_result = MessageBoxW (NULL, L"Again?", L"Browser Test", MB_YESNO);
        if (mb_result == IDNO)
            break;
    }

    CoUninitialize ();
}
```

And if I close the browser (Edge, in my case, running on Windows 10) between the calls to `init` and `browse` I get:

```
browse () returned: 800706ba
```

which is entirely understandable, since this error means "The RPC server unavailable".  It certainly doesn't crash.

---

**Edit**

Stupid Vista bugs, see the OP's recent comments.  After calling `www->Quit()` the next call to `CoCreateInstance()` fails, if you're too quick about it at least.

So, two suggestions.

1 (might work):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    hr = CoCreateInstance (clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IEApplication, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&www));
    if (hr != ERROR_SHUTDOWN_IS_SCHEDULED)    // not really
        break;
    Sleep (1000);
}
```

2 (a bit more drastic, error handling omitted for brevity):

```
// www->Quit ();
HWND hWnd;
hr = www->get_HWND ((SHANDLE_PTR *) &hWnd);
if (hr == S_OK)
{
    DWORD processID;
    if (GetWindowThreadProcessId (hWnd, &processID))
    {
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess (PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, processID);
        if (hProcess)
        {
            TerminateProcess (hProcess, (DWORD) -1);
            CloseHandle (hProcess);
        }
     }
}
```

Want to give it a try, OP, and report back?

Comment: Thanks for giving me some direction. The frequency of the app crashing has reduced. It seems like iexplorer.exe takes time to close, and sometimes never closes. That's when my app crashes. I have actually created a CWebBrowser class. I have updated my post. Any ideas ?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will experiment. Windows 2000 - do you really mean that? And just to confirm, IE11, not Edge.

Comment: I have updated my test program as shown above, and it works fine.  I can't test with IE11 on my platform.  There's an obvious problem in your `init` function (it seems overly complex to me generally) which might or might not be causing you trouble.  What I suggest you do is to run _my_ test program to see if it works on your machine.  If so, you know where to start looking at your own code for bugs.  If not, please get back to me with whatever new information you have and I'll see what I can do (which will probably be not a lot).

Comment: In particular, I need to know what version of Windows you're actually running (can't be W2K, surely).  Thanks.

Comment: appreciate you working on this with me. Following error when trying your code couple of times. 

browse () returned: 0
browse () returned: 0
Assertion failed: hr == 0, file H:\C\Test2\main.cpp, line 49

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information. 

Sorry about the windows version it is server 2018

Comment: OK, I'll update the code tomorrow.  The assert is telling.  Um, AFAICT, there _is_ no Windows server 2018.  Do you mean 2016?

Comment: Oh my what's wrong with me. Sorry Paul its server 2008.

Comment: OK, I see that's based on Windows Vista, could just be buggy.  Are you stuck with that?

Comment: OK, updated the code, let me know what errors are reported in the console.  Pesky Vista.

Comment: CoCreateInstance failed, error 800704a6. I searched online the error relates to Shutdown Initiated. Seems like the error occurs when  iexplorer.exe is in the process of shutting down and CoCreateInstance is called. To verify this I did a test, I kept an instance of iexplorer.exe running and the error did not occur.

Comment: Alllllright, progress, stupid Vista bugs.  I added a couple of ideas to my post.

Comment: Why aren't you setting up an event sink? You *do* get notified, when a browser instance terminates, so all of those workarounds to force the wrong solution to work reliable more frequently are just wasting resources (developer and system).

Comment: @II Sorry, we're just being a bit lazy,  I'll look into it

Comment: @Paul the 1st work-around does not work as (explorer.exe) takes about 30secs to close. The drastic code closes all open browsers. I have noticed that (explorer.exe *32) closes quick. Is it that we need to handle the 64bit (explorer.exe) differently? How do we implement IInspectable's event sink suggestion.

Comment: OK. Sounds like whatever approach we might take, IE is misbehaving.  I am on holiday for a few days and will investigate further on my return.

Comment: @Paul Thank you very much the process id workaround did the trick. I have given you my votes. I had to tweak it to make it work. Although it leaves an (iexplorer.exe) process stuck in task manager. I can live with that :-)

Comment: OK, thanks.  Given your current rep, I don't think you can vote but you can accept, I forget exactly how.  More may be possible here, I'll take another look, but I'm hampered by the fact that I cannot test on Vista.